STM32 VScode tasks.json - where to add include paths
I'm new to VScode for programming STM32 controllers.
I've set up VScode with STM32 extension (using cmake) and CubeMX for windows.
Now, after some struggeling, everything is working fine, except including my own header and source files for building.
As I've learned, tasks.json is the correct place to do this.
As been told in other threads, the folders to be included belong to the "args" property with the option "-I${workspaceFolder}/../..".
At my alread existing tasks.json, I'm using the last task...  "type": "cmake",  "label": "CMake: build",... for building.
But thers is no way to add "args" with the needed include paths.
Could anyone please tell me where or how to add the paths?
Here is my tasks.json file.
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
        "options": {
            "shell": {
                "executable": "cmd.exe",
                "args": ["/d", "/c"]
            }
        }
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "CubeProg: Flash project (SWD)",
            "command": "STM32_Programmer_CLI",
            "args": [
                "--connect",
                "port=swd",
                "--download",
                "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
                "-hardRst",
                "-rst",
                "--start"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Build + Flash",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "CMake: clean rebuild",
                "CubeProg: Flash project (SWD)"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "type": "cmake",
            "label": "CMake: clean rebuild",
            "command": "cleanRebuild",
            "targets": [
                "all"
            ],
            "preset": "${command:cmake.activeBuildPresetName}",
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "detail": "CMake template clean rebuild task"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "CubeProg: List all available communication interfaces",
            "command": "STM32_Programmer_CLI",
            "args": [
                "--list"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "type": "cmake",
            "label": "CMake: build",
            "command": "build",
            "targets": [
                "all"
            ],
            "preset": "${command:cmake.activeBuildPresetName}",
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "detail": "CMake template build task"
        }
    ]
}


Looks like you're using CMake, so you'd do that by adding either include_directories or target_include_directories to your CMakeLists.txt

Adding the include paths to CMakeLists.txt works fine,  but modifying the controller peripherals with STM CubeMX always overwrites CMakeLists.txt. In many comments it is said, that tasks.json is the better way, as it is not overwritten during updating processes.
